# Finite étale cover of factorial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, schemes, picard-group

Let $A$ be a regular factorial ring.
Consider $B=A[X]/(P)$ such that $B$ is finite étale over $A$. When do we have that $B$ is also factorial?

Comment: Rarely. What kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: First baby situation, if $A=C[t]$ for $C$ local regular.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4709515/126807 / See Poonen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even the baby case can fail in positive characteristics, even with $C$ a field. For example, let $p>2$ be the characteristic of an algebraically closed $C$ and take $C[t][x]/(x^p+x+t^{p-1})$.

In characteristic zero, this is correct at least when $B$ is a domain. (I feel one should be able to reduce to this case). Let $A=C[t], B$ as in your comment. Let $R$ be the integral closure of $C$ in $B$. Then we have $A\subset R[t]\subset B$. Let $K$ be the fraction field of $C$. Then $K[t]\subset B\otimes _C K$ is a finite etale extension and in characteristic zero this implies $B\otimes_C K=L[t]$ where $L$ is a finite extension of $K$.  This implies $R[t] $ is birational to $B$. But it is also finite and $R[t]$ is integrally closed. So $R[t]=B$. Since $R$ is a regular ring and a finite extension of a regula local ring, it is semi- local and thus a ufd. So $B$ is also a ufd.